# Creating Android layout with java code in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I add one TextView with the image in this.I want to add a TextView below the imageView.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView imageView;

   if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
       imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(400, 400));
       imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
   }

     imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

     return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use the xml editor and use the an inflater to retrive the java's object?

Comment: Just trying to do it other way.Exploring the possibilites. :)

Comment: Instead of creating an Image view first create a vertical linear layout, then add the image view and then the second view. This second will will be under the image view then.

Comment: We can use java code to make a layout and Java code needed when we want to create dynamic runtime view. Otherwise it would be better to use XML only

Comment: Thanks guys.Really nice of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the xml layout editor to create your Grid's row and use an inflater to retrive the View Java's object. Programmatically, something like

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(context);

parent.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(400, 400));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setId(1)
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
imageView.setId(0);

parent.addView(imageView);
parent.addView(textView);
```

should do it.

`parent` is what `your` getView will return. Of course you will have to change the cast from `ImageView` to `LinearLayout`. you can use `findViewById` with 0 and 1, to retrieve respectively the `ImageView` and the `TextView`, or `getChildAt(0)` and `getChildAt(1)` to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```
     LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(this);
     LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

     LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

     LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

           ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

           //....your imageview code.......


           TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);

           //....your textview code.......


     LL.addView(imageview);
     LL.addView(textview);
```